# Folland's exercise 2.18, proving Fatou's lemma in a more general setting

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying to prove that Fatou's lemma works if $f_n$ is a sequence of measurable functions and $g$ is a non-negative integrable function such that $f_n\ge -g$. That is, it is to be proven that $\int \liminf f_n\le \liminf \int f_n$.

I tried to search a similar question on this site but couldn't find any.

Applying Fatou's lemma to $f_n+g$ gives $$\int(\lim\inf f_n+g)\le \liminf \int f_n+g\tag 1$$

Since $\lim\inf f_n$ need not be integrable, $\int(\lim\inf f_n+g)=\int \liminf f_n +\int g$ is not allowed.  The same can be said about RHS of $(1)$.

$f_n= f_n^+- f_n^-\implies \liminf f_n=-\limsup(f_n^--f_n^+)\ge -\limsup f_n^--\limsup (-f_n^+)=\liminf f_n^+-\limsup f_n^-$.

I'm not sure how to take it from here.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: @OliverDíaz: I think you meant $f_n$ instead of $g$ as $g$ is given to be non negative + integrable.

Comment: On page 12 here http://facultymembers.sbu.ac.ir/shahrokhi/M-P.pdf, and on page 41 here https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/demason/Folland%20Exercises.pdf, there are handwaving solutions, which give no explanation whatsoever.

Comment: @OliverDíaz: I also have that assumption in the post.

Comment: oh! I did not read carefully, I though $g$ was only measurable. Things are easy since $\liminf(f_n+g)=\Big(\liminf_nf_n\Big) + g$

Comment: @OliverDíaz: I understand that $\liminf (a_n+b_n)= \liminf a_n +b$ if $\lim b_n=b$. But that's not the problem. The problem is: why is $\int \liminf (f_n+g)=\int \liminf f_n +\int g$? I think that I have found the answer to the question in OP here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/907519/266435 except there is only one confusion- I don't understand the fourth line after "For the LHS" in the post. Why does the integral break?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139735/discussion-between-oliver-diaz-and-koro).

Comment: If $\liminf f_n$ is integrable easy. Suppose $\liminf_n$ is not integrable. Then either $\int(\liminf f_n)_+=\infty$ or $\int(\liminf f_n)_-=\infty$. 

As $(\liminf_n f_n)+g\geq0$ and $g$ is integrable, $\int(\liminf f_n)_-\neq\infty$. The only alternative is that $\int(\liminf_nf_n)_+=\infty$ and $\int(\liminf_nf_n)_- <\infty$.

Comment: @Ramiro: It does. Thanks a lot :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\liminf f_n$ is integrable easy. Suppose $\liminf_n$ is not integrable. Then either $\int(\liminf f_n)_+=\infty$ or $\int(\liminf f_n)_-=\infty$.

As $(\liminf_n f_n)+g\geq0$ and $g$ is integrable, $\int(\liminf f_n)_-\neq\infty$. The only alternative is that $\int(\liminf_nf_n)_+=\infty$ and $\int(\liminf_nf_n)_- <\infty$.

---

To make things simple suppose $f,g$ are measurable, $g\in L_1$ and $f+g\geq0$ ($g$ may take negative values). Of course  $f\in L_1$ iff $f+g\in L_1$ in which case
$$\int(f+g)=\int f +\int g$$
Assume that $f+g\not\in L_1$. Since $f+g\geq0$, $\int(f+g)$ exists and takes value on $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$, hence $\int(f+g)=\infty$. Let $E=\{f\geq0\}$ so that
$$f+g=(f_+ + g\mathbb{1}_E)-(f_- - g\mathbb{1}_{E^c})$$
On $E^c$ one has $-f_- +g\geq0$ and so,  $0\leq f_-\leq \mathbb{1}_{E^c} g$. It follows that $f_-\in L_1$. Consequently,  $\int(f_+ +g\mathbb{1}_{E})=\infty$ and so, $\int f=\int f_+=\infty$. Therefore
$$\int (f+g)=\int f +\int g$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insights :-).

Comment: @Koro: I just modified my argument to show that the cancellation if $\int g$ can be done in your problem, even in the case where $g\in L_1$ and  allowed to take negative (Still $f_n+g\geq0$)