# Showing $ \int \liminf_{n \to \infty} u_n d\mu \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int u_n d\mu$. Generalized Fatou Lemma, problem 10.7, Schilling

Tags: measure-theory

I'm can't seem to solve problem 10.7 in Schilling's Measure Theory book.
In his solution manual, he gives the proof below, however, in the very first line, he assumes that $\liminf_{n \to \infty} u_n \in \mathscr{L}^1$. How does one deal with the case, where $\liminf_{n \to \infty} u_n \not \in \mathscr{L}^1$?
I keep running into problems with the supremum part of liminf in showing that the rhs of the equality is also infinite.
Here is the problem and given solution:

[image]

[image]

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4548284/304635

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generalization of Fatou's lemma for nonpositive but bounded measurable functions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521179/generalization-of-fatous-lemma-for-nonpositive-but-bounded-measurable-functions)